# HTML loader inside Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that consist of a tab and a html loader animation. I currenty have placed the `loader` inside of my `tab` and what i'm trying to accomplish is that whenever the content inside the tab is fully loaded the html loader animation will just disappear.

Is that an easy way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
  
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

.loader {
    border: 10px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 10px solid #05788C;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #05788C;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="loader">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wowAOdTYqw8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Tokyo</h3>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the following CSS approach:

```
<div class="holds-the-iframe"><iframe here></iframe></div>
.holds-the-iframe {background:url(../images/loader.gif) center center no-repeat;}
```

or change `div class` name to your class Name 'loader'.

```
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="loader">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wowAOdTYqw8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i dont get that

Comment: put your iframe in loader div.

Comment: what is the iframe?

Comment: i have updated the code pls take a look its pretty weird